# Unrecognized Characters ("ï»¿") in User Agent String? What to Do?

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, httpresponse, user-agent

Here are a list of example User Agents that have these mysterious 3 characters appointed right before the Country/Language Code section.

Vi
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/840966/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-27-1251-u-vi-presto-2-8-119-version-11-10

ES (espan.)
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/643853/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-25-729-u-es-presto-2-5-25-version-10-54
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/884994/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-29-3134-u-es-presto-2-8-119-version-11-10

PT
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/874562/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-28-4150-u-pt-presto-2-8-119-version-11-10
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/961801/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-30-3389-u-pt-presto-2-8-119-version-11-10
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/1029731/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-32-952-u-pt-presto-2-8-119-version-11-10

EN (English)
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/911065/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-29-3417-u-en-presto-2-8-119-version-11-10
http://www.webuseragents.com/ua/954938/opera-9-80-j2me-midp-opera-mini-4-2-14912-30-3341-u-en-presto-2-8-119-version-11-10

There is even more but I've left it at that, in every user agent, the unrecognized characters are always the same (that being): "ï»¿" and it will appear as ï»¿Vi or ï»¿PT or ï»¿es or ï»¿en.

Now, it may seem like a foreign word or code, but it shouldn't be. Since all possible User Agent Country (Region) vs Language (locale) reference is listed by Microsoft and is done with normal characters (a-z), rarely numbers (0-9) and dashes (hyphens) and underscores. Nothing more than this is used to describe the hundreds of locales and hundreds of dialects (languages). So, the entire combination of region and languages used in those regions are describable using the ISO 639 standard which uses characters ranging between a-z only.

Microsoft's official list is here, although comprehensive, doesn't cover them all but comes close to it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233968.aspx

So I've examined these 3 characters by turning the symbols into their relevant character code using Visual Studio 2012 and the handy Asc() function, here is how that turned out:

```
ï  = character 239
»  = character 187
¿  = character 191
```

Now, what I really need to know is if User Agents like this are legal UAs. Do I need to throw them in the bin, or pass them on as it (not for any specific purpose, but just generally speaking). Does anyone know anything of this oddity or why it exists, what it's there to represent or anything? The user-Agent specs Special Characters section (in the ISO) makes no reference to this.

Hypothetically speaking, if i were to write a program that analyzed a User Agent and returned to a user its legitimacy, what would a User Agent with the ï»¿ characters dictate I return? User Agent is Legit (True) or Not Legit (False)...?

**UPDATE/ADDITION:**

I found another User Agent with similar issues, it displays like this (notice part right after JUC):

```
JUC (DÌFH©3;U; 2.3.5; zh-cn; HTC_Explorer_A310e; 320*480)
```

However, in my text stream, I see it as "`D?FH?3`", so I have all these question marks that are replacing the original strange characters.

I am using System.Net.WebClient's .DownloadData subroutine to get this data, and I'm guessing that is where the conversion is happening (unless LINK To Entity is doing it, since the database field type I'm storing it in is `nvarchar(MAX)`).

What should I do? Should I get this data in it's original form and pass it on "as is" or should I just exclude all items with strange characters?

I mean, does, for instance, DÌFH©3 represent a real product name made and used in china? Any ideas on which direction I should go?

Thank you very much all, for reading and for any anticipated response.

Comment: Looks like the user agent has filled in some UTF-8 encoded characters... Have you tried setting the request header encoding of your website to UTF-8?

Comment: EDIT: it seems that the UTF-8 expands to 0xFEFF - the byte order mark for unicode textfiles... seems some weird encoding problems in the user agents or somebody along the way read a textfile with the BOM and forgot to skip it, then sent the UTF-8 equivalent...

Comment: @RomanGruber Just added some more information. Do you think the strange text represents something real or should entries like this be ignored completely? I am downloading these UA's from botsvsbrowsers.com

Comment: it might be meaningful, but it's not very polite to encode such technical info with non-english characters. I'm guessing that either the strings are stored wrong on the webserver or that the webserver sends the wrong content type encoding for the text data. What's the server settings for that download? If ASP.NET you might check the "globalization" settings or override the encoding in the Response object to match with UTF-8. The "?" results from unicode/ascii conversion when an "invalid" character is found. nvarchar is good for unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The website is assuming that this the user agent string was encoded as ISO-8859-1, but it was in fact UTF-8.

What you're seeing is Unicode codepoint U+FEFF (a.k.a. "[BYTE ORDER MARK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)"). When encoded in UTF-8, it's made up of the three bytes 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF. When you assume those three bytes are actually ISO-8859-1, you would encode them as `ï»¿`.

The byte order mark can always be safely stripped from UTF-8 strings. For other encoding schemes (UCS-2, UTF-16, etc.) it might be a useful hint for the decoder, but again, it has no other purpose or meaning.

When you're dealing with UA strings first-hand, your best bet is probably to try to decode it as UTF-8, and interpret everything that's not in the Letter, Number, Mark, or Symbol category as spaces.